# Are streams handled by multiple threads in project-reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

I am starting to go through Spring's Project Reactor Core reference and I have a few questions, that I am yet to find answer to:

- *How are threads involved in stream processing?*
- *Can subscribers of a single stream be executed by multiple threads?*
- *Can terminate event be fired before all subscribers finishes processing the last item?*

I know basics of NodeJS event loop, but I am not sure if this is the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are threads involved in stream processing?

It's up to you. Use `publishOn` or `subscribeOn` to jump execution of part of a pipeline to another `Thread` (as represented by the `Scheduler` abstraction). Or use time-related operators: these operate on the `Schedulers.parallel()` scheduler by default, and can be fine tuned. Any other operator (that doesn't have an override which takes a `Scheduler`) operates on the same `Thread` it received its data (`onNext` signal) from.

> Can subscribers of a single stream be executed by multiple threads?

Not quite: per `Reactive Streams` specification `onNext` events must be sequential and MUST NOT happen in parallel. `Flux#parallel(n).runOn(Scheduler)` introduces an explicit exception to this rule.

> Can terminate event be fired before all subscribers finishes processing the last item?

Each "subscriber" (call to `subscribe`, `block*`) sees and generates its own "stream". So in regards to the lambda(s) that you pass to `subscribe`, `onComplete` is never executed before or at the same time as `onNext` consumer.

Only exception is if you have a "hot" source, one that plays the same events to all its subscribers. In which case late subscribers will only see the elements that got emitted after they came in (and if such subscriber subscribes AFTER the original sequence has completed, then it will see NO `onNext` and will immediately `onComplete`).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I guess pretty crucial source (which I found after writing my question) is this - https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#specification .